# Fibonacci Sequence "Show the mathematical sequence"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now all I got is it generating the fib sequence I want to show the mathematical sequence after the result. ex. 8+13 = 21

How can I achieve this?

**HTML**:

```
<div id="genhere"></div>
```

**JavaScript/JQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log = function(message) {
        $('#genhere').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
    };

    console.error = console.debug = console.info = console.log;

    var fib = function(numMax) {
        for(a=0, b=1, c=0; c<numMax; a=b, b=x, c++){
            x=a+b;
            console.log(x);
        }
    };

    fib(50);
});
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting `console.log`? Why are you using global variables?

Comment: The answers so far involve using the console to show the results. But do you want the answer inside the `genhere` div instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(a + ' + ' + b + ' = ' + x);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Kagz/

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood, are you meaning to print something similar?

```
console.log(a+"+"+b+"="+x);
```